# vectorize lookup values in table of interval limits

Tags: matlab, loops, octave, vectorization

Here is a question about whether we can use vectorization type of operation in matlab to avoid writing for loop.

I have a vector

```
Q = [0.1,0.3,0.6,1.0]
```

I generate a uniformly distributed random vector over `[0,1)`

```
X = [0.11,0.72,0.32,0.94]
```

I want to know whether each entry of `X` is between `[0,0.1)` or `[0.1,0.3)` or `[0.3,0.6)`, or `[0.6,1.0)` and I want to return a vector which contains the index of the maximum element in `Q` that each entry of `X` is less than.

I could write a for loop

```
Y = zeros(length(X),1)
for i = 1:1:length(X)
    Y(i) = find(X(i)<Q, 1);
end
```

Expected result for this example:

```
Y = [2,4,3,4]
```

But I wonder if there is a way to avoid writing for loop? (I see many very good answers to my question. Thank you so much! Now if we go one step further, what if my Q is a matrix, such that I want check whether )

```
Y = zeros(length(X),1)
for i = 1:1:length(X)
    Y(i) = find(X(i)<Q(i), 1);
end
```

Comment: Why would Q be a matrix? What would Q be, and what would the desired output be?

Comment: I mean each row of Q would be a similar vector like [0.1,0.3,0.6,1.0], then I want to do the operation find(X(i)<Q(i), 1), where i is the running index. If it can be done using vectorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octave does a neat auto-vectorization trick for you if the vectors you have are along different dimensions. If you make `Q` a column vector, you can do this:

```
X = [0.11, 0.72, 0.32, 0.94];
Q = [0.1; 0.3; 0.6; 1.0; 2.0; 3.0];
X <= Q
```

The result is a 6x4 matrix indicating which elements of `Q` each element of `X` is less than. I made `Q` a different length than `X` just to illustrate this:

```
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
1   0   1   0
1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1
```

Going back to the original example you have, you can do

```
length(Q) - sum(X <= Q) + 1
```

to get

```
2   4   3   4
```

Notice that I have semicolons instead of commas in the definition of `Q`. If you want to make it a column vector after defining it, do something like this instead:

```
length(Q) - sum(X <= Q') + 1
```

The reason that this works is that Octave implicitly applies `bsxfun` to an operation on a row and column vector. MATLAB will not do this until R2016b according to @excaza's comment, so in MATLAB you can do this:

```
length(Q) - sum(bsxfun(@le, X, Q)) + 1
```

You can play around with this example in IDEOne [here](https://ideone.com/g2VRtL).

Comment: I cannot get this to work, are you sure about this ?

Comment: I changed `Q` to `Q'` using semicolons instead of explicitly. Will make more explicit.

Comment: This is elegant!  Thanks! I also modified my OP a little bit, what if Q is a matrix, will this method also works?

Comment: This may be only an octave trick because I have MATLAB running right now and it doesn't work on MATLAB

Comment: @ftxx. Did you test this with actual MATLAB or are you really using Octave?

Comment: I am also not able to reproduce the result with your code on MATLAB

Comment: @RandomGuy is correct, I found that Matlab doesn't have this feature, but Octave does.

Comment: Would you consider adding `octave` tag to your qn or should I delete my answer?

Comment: MATLAB *does* have this feature, Octave is just using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) implicitly. MATLAB's equivalent is `length(Q) - sum(bsxfun(@le, X, Q)) + 1`. Implicit `bsxfun` is being introduced to MATLAB in R2016b

Comment: @ftxx. I fixed my answer to work with MATLAB. I think this is probably the simplest one-liner now.

Comment: Thanks! this looks very elegant. I am just curious, what if Q is a matrix, as stated in the last part of my post, is there a similar way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Elegant enough to select?

Comment: @MadPhysicist why nobody look at my solution at the bottom? I think it is also good

Answer (score 8):

Use the second output of [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), which acts as a sort of "vectorized `find`":

```
[~, Y] = max(bsxfun(@lt, X(:).', Q(:)), [], 1);
```

**How this works**:

1. For each element of `X`, test if it is less than each element of `Q`. This is done with `bsxfun(@lt, X(:).', Q(:))`. Note each column in the result corresponds to an element of `X`, and each row to an element of `Q`.
2. Then, for each element of `X`, get the index of the first element of `Q` for which that comparison is `true`. This is done with `[~, Y] = max(..., [], 1)`. Note that the second output of `max` returns the index of the *first* maximizer (along the specified dimension), so in this case it gives the index of the first `true` in each column.

For your example values,

```
Q = [0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1.0];
X = [0.11, 0.72, 0.32, 0.94];
[~, Y] = max(bsxfun(@lt, X(:).', Q(:)), [], 1);
```

gives

```
Y =
     2     4     3     4
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `bsxfun` will help accomplish this. You'll need to read about it. I also added a Q = 0 at the beginning to handle the small X case

```
X = [0.11,0.72,0.32,0.94 0.01];
Q = [0.1,0.3,0.6,1.0];
Q_extra = [0 Q];

Diff = bsxfun(@minus,X(:)',Q_extra (:)); %vectorized subtraction
logical_matrix = diff(Diff < 0); %find the transition from neg to positive
[X_categories,~] = find(logical_matrix == true); % get indices
```

% output is 2 4 3 4 1

**EDIT: How long does each method take?**

I got curious about the difference between each solution:

Test Code Below:

```
Q = [0,0.1,0.3,0.6,1.0];

X = rand(1,1e3);

tic
Y = zeros(length(X),1);
for i = 1:1:length(X)
    Y(i) = find(X(i)<Q, 1);
end
toc
tic
result = arrayfun(@(x)find(x < Q, 1), X);
toc

tic
Q = [0 Q];
Diff = bsxfun(@minus,X(:)',Q(:)); %vectorized subtraction
logical_matrix = diff(Diff < 0); %find the transition from neg to positive
[X_categories,~] = find(logical_matrix == true); % get indices
toc
```

Run it for yourself, I found that when the size of X was 1e6, bsxfun was much faster, while for smaller arrays the differences were varying and negligible.

SAMPLE: when size X was 1e3

```
Elapsed time is 0.001582 seconds. % for loop
Elapsed time is 0.007324 seconds. % anonymous function
Elapsed time is 0.000785 seconds. % bsxfun
```

Comment: DMR's answer is much simpler code, but this is a bit more readable and slightly faster. This could be smashed into a single line, but brevity is not necessarily the goal, especially when trying to help other learn

Comment: Agree, `bsxfun` is usually the fastest implementation between a for loop and an anonymous function.

Answer (score 4):

Octave has a function `lookup` to do exactly that. It takes a lookup table of sorted values and an array, and returns an array with indices for values in the lookup table.

```
octave> Q = [0.1 0.3 0.6 1.0];
octave> x = [0.11 0.72 0.32 0.94];
octave> lookup (Q, X)
ans =

   1   3   2   3
```

The only issue is that your lookup table has an implicit zero which be fixed easily with:

```
octave> lookup ([0 Q], X) # alternatively, just add 1 at the results
ans =

   2   4   3   4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an anonymous function to perform the comparison, then apply it to each member of X using `arrayfun`:

```
compareFunc = @(x)find(x < Q, 1);
result = arrayfun(compareFunc, X, 'UniformOutput', 1);
```

The Q array will be stored in the anonymous function ( `compareFunc` ) when the anonymous function is created.

Or, as one line (Uniform Output is the default behavior of arrayfun):

```
result = arrayfun(@(x)find(x < Q, 1), X);
```

Comment: I've edited it to give a numeric array (Uniform Output now set to 1)

Comment: Clever, very simple code, although it may be slow depending on how efficient arrayfun is.

Comment: @DMR I wonder if my Q is a matrix, and I want to check find(x(i) < Q(i,:),1), how to implement this idea use this arrayfunc?

Comment: @Trogdor, are you saying that this method may be even slower than just write a for loop?

Comment: no, I did a quick test, and this approach is ~ 6 times faster than a for loop, EDIT: double checked and it looks like this approach is faster on small arrays than mine

Comment: update, looks like this answer can be slower than a for loop for large data sets.

Comment: `arrayfun` is basically a glorified version of a `for` loop. I wouldn't consider this vectorized TBH. No insult intended to your approach though of course.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the solution posted by @Mad Physicist, here is my solution.

```
Q = [0.1,0.3,0.6,1.0]   
X = [0.11,0.72,0.32,0.94] 
Temp = repmat(X',1,4)<repmat(Q,4,1)
[~, ind]= max( Temp~=0, [], 2 );
```

The idea is that make the X and Q into the "same shape", then use element wise comparison, then we obtain a logical matrix whose row tells whether a given element in X is less than each of the element in Q, then return the first non-zero index of each row of this logical matrix. I haven't tested how fast this method is comparing to other methods